# Azure DevOps change Agent Pool

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to set a build pipeline to run on a specific agent pool. At the moment it insists on working on the "Azure Pipelines" pool:

[image: Azure DevOps agent pools screen]

However I'm not able to change the build pipeline's agent pool (at least I'm not sure how).

My YAML looks like this:

```yaml
trigger:

- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'

- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Pack the package'
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    configuration: 'Release'
    packagesToPack: 'NugetComponents/**/*.csproj'
    nobuild: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

I'm not sure if I need to change anything here. I can't find anything in the interface for configuring which agent bool a pipeline should use?

Comment: Did you look at the YAML documentation? It explains how to specify agent pools in great detail.

Comment: @DanielMann yea I looked at the docs but it wasn't clear that I needed to specify a name property.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this doc about agent pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#default-agent-pools), the “Azure Pipelines” pool contains various Windows, Linux , and macOS images.

> The Azure Pipelines hosted pool replaces the previous hosted pools
>   that had names that mapped to the corresponding images. Any jobs you
>   had in the previous hosted pools are automatically redirected to the
>   correct image in the new Azure Pipelines hosted pool.

So when you specify Microsoft-hosted agent ( e.g. Ubuntu-latest) , the pipeline will run on the “Azure Pipelines” pool.

**Update**

You can specify the target agent pool in the “pool” field.

This is the format of Yaml:

```
pool:
  name: string  
  demands: string 
  vmImage: string
```

For Microsoft-hosted agents: you can directly specify “vmImage”.

For example:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
```

For Self-hosted agents: you can specify agent pool name.

For example:

```
pool:
  name: Agent Pool name
```

Here is a doc about [specifying agent pool in Yaml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#pool).

Comment: Hey Kevin, it turns out that I needed to use the name property to specify the pool in the yaml file.

Comment: @PrimeByDesign Yes. You are right. I have updated my answer. Hope these can help you.